# How does caret calculate F1 score?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I'm using caret to compute multiple ML models and compare them. However, I have seen that the F1-score calculated by the models doesn't seem to be what I expected.

The formula for F1-score should be this one: 2 x [(Precision x Recall) / (Precision + Recall)].

However, when I run caret, the calculated F1-score doesn't seem to work like that.

The code I ran is the following one:

```
  control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=k_folds_cross_validation, repeats=times_cross_validation, search = "random",
                          summaryFunction = multiClassSummary, returnResamp = "all", savePredictions = "all", classProbs =  TRUE)
  set.seed(7)
  tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 0, lambda = 10^seq(-4, 0, length.out = 50))
  lasso_ML <- train(t(x), y, method = "glmnet", trControl = control, family="binomial", tuneGrid = tuneGrid , metric="F1")
```

And when running `lasso_ML$results` I see a table such as the following one (I didn't put all the columns)

```
  alpha       lambda    F1 Precision     Recall
1     0 0.0001000000 0.625      0.55 0.05833333
2     0 0.0001206793 0.625      0.55 0.05833333
3     0 0.0001456348 0.625      0.55 0.05833333
4     0 0.0001757511 0.625      0.55 0.05833333
5     0 0.0002120951 0.625      0.55 0.05833333
6     0 0.0002559548 0.625      0.55 0.05833333
```

How can it be? Theoretically the F1-score should be 0.1054794, not 0.625.

Comment: Because those are averaged over the repeated-k-fold folds, you can't expect the average F1 score to be the same as the F1 using the averaged precision and recall.  That said, this seems so far out of range that there's likely another issue.  Can you find the individual fold scores to confirm?

Comment: How can I access the F1 scores over the repeated k-folds?